# configuring httpd with valid/invalid IPs

Tags: web-server, httpd

Our server have to network interfaces. First has a valid IP which we run httpd and the second has an internal IP (192.168.X.X). More information listed below

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1      localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.1.5    srv1



# cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/munin
   ServerName 124.205.99.114
   ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
   CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
      <Directory /var/www/html/munin>
        Satisfy any
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As I restart the httpd, I see a warning which is

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.5 for ServerName
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

You may say that this is just a warning, but when I enter the IP address in the web browser, the index.html file is not shown and I get `The connection has timed out`

UPDATE:

Seems that the warning is not related to the "time out" problem. The output of `iptables -nvL` is as bellow

```
# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1334K  146M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   17   736 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1259  486K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  964 56148 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
    5   300 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:2049
60244 7018K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1183K packets, 1247M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

UPDATE 2:

I allowed the port 80 with this command

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

it can be verified with this output

```
# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
....
61165 7150K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80
```

I restarted the services `network` and `httpd` but still I can not open index.html in the browser.

Comment: An IP address is not a `ServerName`! `srv1.example.com` is a server name.

Comment: But we don't have a domain (example.com) yet. We will test with http:// 124.205.99.114

Comment: I didn't say you did, I'm just telling you why you get that warning. If you look at a missing page (e.g. 404) or a generated directory listing, it will report that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to edit your `httpd.conf` file and set :

```
ServerName 192.168.1.5:80
```

Also, in `iptables`, you don't have a rule to allow state `NEW` on port `80` :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

You already have the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` state.

Comment: Please see the updated post

Comment: The `ACCEPT` is after the `REJECT`. It should be before. Order is important with `iptables`

Comment: When I run "iptables -A INPUT..." it will automatically append the rule so it will appear after the REJECT.

Comment: What is your OS ? My guess is `CentOS` : have a look to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Comment: Use `-I` (capital i) instead of `-A` so that the rule gets inserted at the top of the list.  Since the rule ended up after the `REJECT` rule, the packets are rejected and the new rule will never be used.

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes from the fact there is no fqdn entry associated to 192.168.1.5 in your /etc/hosts file. The connection timeout issue is something else. Maybe you have firewall rules prohibiting confections to the host.
Check that with iptables -nvL

Comment: See the updated post

Comment: Http port 80 is not allowed. That's why you have this timeout.

Comment: Which line you are referring? Please update your post with a solution. How can I add that to the firewall?

Comment: iptables -I INPUT 4 -m tcp -p tcp --sport1024: --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

Comment: sport is not supported by Scientific Linux. See the updated post

Comment: Yes that's because you didn't use the correct command, hence appending the new rule after the reject rule. Which is not particularly clever. That work at first try if you do it as advised...